# GUI automation of program with changing menu options

Tags: automation, ui-automation

I'm looking to automate software on Windows 2008. The automation software doesn't have to be Windows 2008 compatible (I can use remote desktop). 
The GUI has two main areas, a list of embedded images on the left, and a display pane on the right. The display pane shows where all the embedded images have been placed on the screen (the program is used for building Human Machine Interfaces [HMI's]).

I need to click each of the embedded images in the list on the left and extract some data from them. **The problem is; depending on main display file chosen, the list of embedded images will have different names and be of different lengths.**

The automated task therefore changes depending on main display image file opened. Is there an automation program that can be customized for this? I could write separate scripts for each main display file but this defeats the purpose of automating. I looked into Sikuli, AutoIt, pywinauto and others, but have not found examples of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Question looks too wide so far. What exactly did you try? Maybe Spy++ or Inspect.exe? Is the image names are visible to these programs? Spy++ can be replaced by AutoItWindowInfo tool that is a clone of Spy++. But Inspect.exe can usually show you much more data, because UI Automation is more powerful than Win32 API. AFAIK AutoIt and AutoHotKey don't support UI Automation. Pywinauto does.

Comment: Running script on local machine is usually impossible because Remote Desktop doesn't provide GUI elements info transparently. So you have to copy the script to target remote machine and run it by psexec, for example. Or using Jenkins agent as not a service + VNC server instead of Remote Desktop. But this is separate question not related to particular automation tool/library.

Comment: `Inspect.exe` can be found here: https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) can do what you're asking for with little difficulty.

You can use some basic OOP principles to write one program that has different clicking locations etc. based on which display file you're running.